# SQL COALESCE and IS NULL are not returning a space when when the query returns NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coalesce, isnullorempty

I am trying to optimize a humongous SQL query that was written by a self taught developer that used a ton of functions instead of JOINS.  Anyway, I am having trouble displaying a space or a empty string('') when there is no value in the field selected.  I've included only the SELECT in question.  I am having the weirdest problem or just overlooking the correct answer in troubleshooting.  Whenever I use COALESCE, when the field is supposed to be a blank string, it displays a zero.  And when I use IS NULL, I get back NULL.  All info online seems to point toward using COALESCE(value, '') as depicted in the code.  But I am getting a 0 instead of ''.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I'm using SSMS.

```
SELECT      
pss8.dbo.xml_StripIllegalChars(dbo.rpt_get_series_volume(b.bookkey)) AS p_seriesvol --SELECT to be replaced that works but is slow due to function use I am told
,COALESCE(bd.seriesvolume, '') AS p_seriesvol  --my SELECT that won't work!
FROM 
    bookdetail bd
WHERE 
    --bd.bookkey='303177'
    bd.bookkey='6002'
```

The bookkeys at the bottom are for testing as I know the top one returns a 1 and the bottom one returns a '' previously when it worked.  The SELECT above my commented SELECT is the code that works but is slow...  According to what I read online, I am saying 'if there isn't a series volume number, then it equals an empty string.'  Does COALESCE not work like this?  Can it only return a 0 if the field has no value, or in this case, has no volume number?  All help much appreciated.  I'm very curious to hear a solution!

Here's more intel.  This is how the this SELECT works:
`pss8.dbo.xml_StripIllegalChars(dbo.rpt_get_series_volume(b.bookkey)) AS p_seriesvol`

The

```
.rpt_get_series_vol
```

function manages to create an empty string with this code... Does this reveal anything?

```
    DECLARE @RETURN              
    VARCHAR(5)
    DECLARE @v_desc              
    VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @i_volumenumber         INT
SELECT @i_volumenumber = volumenumber
FROM    bookdetail
WHERE   bookkey = @i_bookkey and volumenumber <> 0


IF @i_volumenumber > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @RETURN = CAST(@i_volumenumber as varchar(5))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT @RETURN = ''
END

RETURN @RETURN
END
```

Comment: If COALESCE(bd.seriesvolume, '') returns 0 then the value of bd.seriesvolume *is* 0 (i.e. not NULL).

Comment: ahhh.  what if I want a 0 then to be a empty string or converted to one within this column only.. or this SELECT? Thanks!  For example `if bd.volumenumber = 0 THEN bd.volumenumber = '' `?

Comment: What datatype is the bd.seriesvolume column?

Comment: Its a varchar(5)

Comment: In defense of "self taught developers", some of us do know stuff. :)

Comment: Oh I know @EricBrandt.  I just meant to say he solved a ton of problems  in an out of the box way.  I am only fixing what others say 'could be done differently and better.'  I am self taught too!  Still Stuck on this though...

Comment: So, the function finds `p_seriesvol` based on the value of `bd.volumenumber`, but in your `COALESCE`, you're using `bd.seriesvolume`. Could you post the tuples of (`bd.bookkey`,`bd.volumenumber`,`bd.seriesvolume`) for the `bookkey`s '303177' and '6002', and their data types (we know `seriesvolume` is varchar(5))?

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking for a `'0'` not a `NULL` `COALESCE()`is not useful, instead use a simple `CASE`:

```
select
    ...,
    case bd.seriesvolume when '0' then '' else bd.seriesvolume end as p_seriesvol 
from
    ...
```

Or if you want `''` for `0` or `NULL`

```
case when bd.seriesvolume is null or bd.seriesvolume = '0' then '' else bd.seriesvolume end as p_seriesvo
```

Comment: strange... I'm still getting a 0 or NULL using both solutions.  It looks right and I def tried these options.  For some reason I'm still getting NULL or 0.  First gives NULL and the second gives 0.  I am expecting both to provide a space... Isn't that weird?  if the value I'm looking for is 0, then how is my query changing it to NULL?  NULL isn't mentioned as an option...

Comment: does the function within the original SELECT that I added to my question change anything you were thinking?

Answer (score 0):

```
COALESCE() function returns the 1st non null value
```

`SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value');` returns the third value because the third value is the first value that is not null.

So in your case `COALESCE(bd.seriesvolume, '')` AS p_seriesvol if seriesvolume colum value is  null then it will return blank string

Comment: thanks but that's exactly what my code says I tried and its not working.  I need to try new things or alter that.

Comment: it doesn't.  I'm still confused.  I'm looking to figure out the whole issue.  I got your answer from @Alex K but he went a step further and explained more.  You just explained his first point. If I were to select an anser it would be his.

Comment: @Rob then mark his answer as a correct answer .. actually i meant if any ones answer helps then mark it as a correct answer

Comment: its seems correct but I'm still having issues.  Stop telling me what to do passively.  You're annoying me and misdirecting the focus.  please.  hit up another question